# Rake db:drop not clearing out my old tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rake, rails-migrations

My User migration used to look like this:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :login
      etc
```

Now it looks like this:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :username
      etc
```

Why, then, do I see this?

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
rails console
> User.new
+----+-------+------------------+---------------+-------------------+------------+------------+
| id | login | crypted_password | password_salt | persistence_token | created_at | updated_at |
+----+-------+------------------+---------------+-------------------+------------+------------+
|    |       |                  |               |                   |            |            |
+----+-------+------------------+---------------+-------------------+------------+------------+
1 row in set
```

I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Did you change an existing migration, or did you add a new one?

Comment: You inspired to change on digit in the filename of the migration and that forced it to reload. Rails must have been caching the migration's contents. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incrementing the filename of the User migration solved the problem. I presume Rails was caching the contents of the migration when I tried to change its contents without changing the filename.